# can someone please help how I can do the below regex?

Tags: regex

I want to get **141d 3h 2m 54s** from the following using RegEx. 
**2016-04-07 18:59:59 CDT (141d 3h 2m 54s from now)**

Comment: More information is needed. What programming language are you using? Regex may not even be the most appropriate solution.

Comment: I tried using this <%="2016-04-07 18:59:59 CDT (141d 3h 2m 54s from now)".Replace(".*$\(","") %>. to remove everything before (. but no luck

Comment: Are you asking how to get a sub-string enclosed in parentheses?

Comment: Add all the details to your question by using [edit].

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 0):

If the format is constant, this will give you what you need

```
(?<=\().+s
```

Actually, interesting enough -

```
\((.+s)
```

reduces it down to 17 steps.

Answer (score 0):

Well this works in Oracle, maybe you can adjust the regex to work in whatever language you are using.

```
select regexp_replace('2016-04-07 18:59:59 CDT (141d 3h 2m 54s from now)',
                     '.*\((.*s) .*', '\1')                  
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Match match;
match = Regex.Match(input string,@"\d+d\s+\d+h\s+\d+m\s+\d+s");
```

match.value gives you the required answer